# checking if sum of any 3 numbers of list equals 0 (python)

Tags: python-3.x

i want to develop a function that receives a list of numbers and returns 'True' if the sum of any 3 of those numbers equals to 0 and returns False if it doesn't.
for example, if i input [2,2,1,-1,0], the output should be 'True', since 1-1+0=0

```
def sum3(list):
    list=map(str,list)
    for a in list:
        for b in list:
            for c in list:
                if int(a)+int(b)+int(c)==0:
                     return True
                else:
                    return False
```

so far i have this code, but it only works it the sum of the FIRST three numbers equals to three.

Comment: Move `return False` to after all your loops have finished.

Comment: it worked, thanks aha

Comment: Unrelated to question, but your code will add 3 of the same item. input `[0]` will result in True was well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you `map` to `strings` and then convert back to integers so I removed that although it wasn't crucial to fixing it. Also, you should rename your parameter to `l` (or equivalent) instead of `list` as this overrides the built-in `list()` function.

---

The main thing was to move the `return False` to outside the 3 `for-loops` so that it only returns once *all* combinations have been evaluated. You also need to only search for elements that are further in the list than the one currently being evaluated. As otherwise (pointed our by `@Hazerd`) if there is a `0` then the function will return `True` as `0` will come up as `a`, `b` and `c` at once.

This gives the corrected function:

```
def sum3(l):
    for a in range(len(l)):
        for b in range(a+1, len(l)):
            for c in range(b+1, len(l)):
                if l[a]+l[b]+l[c] == 0:
                     return True
    return False
```

and some tests show it works:

```
>>> sum3([2, 2, 1, -1, 0])
True
>>> sum3([0, 1, 2])
False
```

Comment: There is nothing preventing a,b,c from being different (in the question and your answer). If `0` exists anywhere in the list it will return true, because 0+0+0=0.